# How to limit the failed job retry counter with ActiveJob and Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby, rails-activejob

I would like to limit the number of `retries` when a job fails using `ActiveJob` with `Sidekiq` as adapter.

Using Sidekiq, I can do that:

```
class LessRetryableWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :retry => 5

  def perform(...)
  end
end
```

Sidekiq configuration doesn't provide a global `retry` config. Each Worker is responsible of setting the `retry` option. So I guess I have to implement it in ActiveJob side to do it properly.

Comment: We built a gem to do just this! It's still in alpha, so please report any issues you find. https://github.com/SimplyBuilt/activejob-retriable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Sidekiq` provide a server-level config to handle this case.
From `Sidekiq` ruby-doc:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Middleware::Server::RetryJobs, :max_retries => 7
  end
end
```