# Disable automatic retry with ActiveJob, used with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Is there a way to disable automatic retry with ActiveJob and Sidekiq ?

I know that with Sidekiq only, we just have to put

```
sidekiq_options :retry => false
```

as mentioned here : https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration

but it doesn't seem to work with ActiveJob and Sidekiq.

I also know the solution to entierly disable the retry as proposed here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216822/2431728

But it's not the behavior I need.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok thanks for the answer.

Just for information, I also asked the question in an issue related to this subject on ActiveJob Github repository : https://github.com/rails/activejob/issues/47

DHH answered me a solution I haven't tested but that can do the job.

Personnally, I finally put this in an initializer in order to disable Sidekiq retries globally and it works well :

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
   config.server_middleware do |chain|
      chain.add Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::RetryJobs, :max_retries => 0
   end
end
```

Comment: actually, you can remove the `RetryJobs` middleware as shown [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware#default-middleware)

Comment: Sidekiq has a builtin way to turn off retries globally: `Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { retry: 0 }`

Comment: @Ari I don't believe that works for ActiveJob though... only for native Sidekiq workers without AJ

Comment: @courtsmas  `Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::RetryJobs` was removed in 5.0.0 so it seems that only  way to disable now is `Sidekiq.options[:max_retries] = 0`.

Answer (score 29):

As of `sidekiq 6.0.1`, it is possible to pass the following to an ActiveJob worker to prevent it from retrying:

```
class ExampleJob < ActiveJob::Base
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(*args)
    # Perform Job
  end
end
```

More information: [https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#customizing-error-handling](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#customizing-error-handlinghttps://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#customizing-error-handling)

**EDIT:**

According to [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4281) this requires Rails `6.0.1` or later as well.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to configure anything about Sidekiq with ActiveJob.  Use a Sidekiq Worker if you don't want to use the defaults.

Comment: Even if we use an initializer, and the settings are as follows? Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { 'backtrace' => 5, 'retry' => 3 }

Answer (score 8):

You can catch up the exception and to do nothing instead retry or to configure retry:

```
  class ExampleJob < ActiveJob::Base
    rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
      Rails.logger.error "[#{self.class.name}] Hey, something was wrong with you job #{exception.to_s}"       
    end

    def perform
      raise StandardError, "error_message"
    end
  end

  class ExampleJob < ActiveJob::Base
    rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
      retry_job wait: 5.minutes, queue: :low_priority     
    end

    def perform
      raise StandardError, "error_message"
    end
  end
```

For running retrying you can use retry_on method [retry_on method doc](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe1f4b2ad56f010a4e9b93d547d63a15953d9dc2/activejob/lib/active_job/exceptions.rb#L26)

[Sidekiq wiki for retries with Active Job integration](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#customizing-error-handling)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same need, ie ActiveJob wrapping Sidekiq but wanting to support max_retries.  I put this in an initializer. If #max_retries is defined on an ActiveJob job, it will be used to set retries. If #ephemeral? is defined and returns true, job will not be rerun and will not be transferred to 'dead' if it fails.

```
class Foobar::SidekiqClientMiddleware
  def call(worker_class, msg, queue, redis_pool)
    aj_job = ActiveJob::Base.deserialize(msg['args'][0]) rescue nil
    msg['retry'] = aj_job.respond_to?(:max_retries) ? aj_job.max_retries : 5
    msg['retry'] = false if aj_job.respond_to?(:ephemeral?) && aj_job.ephemeral?
    yield
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{redis_host}:6379/12" }
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Foobar::SidekiqClientMiddleware
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{redis_host}:6379/12" }
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Foobar::SidekiqClientMiddleware
  end
end
```

Note: it actually is important to add this to the middleware chain for both client and server if any of your jobs create new jobs themselves as they are executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable retry (or add any other Sidekiq options) for `ActiveJob` from gems (like for `ActionMailbox::RoutingJob`), you can use this approach (Rails 6.0.2+).

1) Create a module with the desired Sidekiq options (using `ActiveSupport::Concern`)

```rb
# lib/fixes/action_mailbox_routing_job_sidekiq_fix.rb

module ActionMailboxRoutingJobSidekiqFix
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    sidekiq_options retry: false
  end
end
```

2) Include it in the job class in an initializer.

```rb
# config/initializers/extensions.rb

require Rails.root.join('lib', 'fixes', 'action_mailbox_routing_job_sidekiq_fix')

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  ActionMailbox::RoutingJob.include ::ActionMailboxRoutingJobSidekiqFix
end
```